# Azure SQL DTU Spike Handling Ideas?

Tags: azure, redis

We have an SQL Database at S1 pricing tear with 100 DTU's, everything works fine but when our website get a traffic spike the DTU exceed 99% of the usage and need a manual scale else things stop to work.

Any ideas how to handle spike should we put up Redis and serve cached data instead of directly from the DB? Is this the best possible solution.

Looking for ideas

Answer (score 2):

By all means, Azure Redis is an excellent solution for that scenario, but first, you have to do the following:

1. Use [this query](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/) to find which queries are the most CPU intensive.
2. Optimize those queries, either by refactoring them or [adding indexes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-index-advisor/).
3. Once you cannot optimize your DB any further, set a caching strategy. If you are using Web Apps with multiple instances, use a distributed cache solution (like Azure Redis) and store **the most used pieces of information that are constly to build and common to the vast majority of your users**. If you don't use multiple instances, you can opt for In-memory cache, but it really depends on the Size of your instances.

Answer (score 0):

You should cache public data which is not changing frequently. Let's say you have annoucements on your main page. You have just maximum 1 annoucment for 1 hour then cache it.

But you shouldn't cache private data. Espicially if they are sensitive and changing frequently eg:customer balance.

You should have proper indexes.

If you have logs/audit, you should use another db for this. Table storage is good for this.